# assigning environmental variables and running shell scripts within python

Tags: python, shell

I'm new to python, and trying to use it to set up batch processing for an openfoam simulation which will require python (3.6) to execute a shell script. Normally, to run the sim in the bash terminal I would just execute:

```
foam6 #alias defined in .bashrc to set up environmental variables
./run
```

So, in python I tried:  `subprocess.run(["sh","/home/michael/.bashrc",";","foam6",";"./run"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

The output of this is blank, with a return code of 0. But the script never starts. I've gotten similar behavior when trying subprocess.call() or similar functions or the os.system command. Anyone have suggestions what I could try?

Comment: If you can afford to have the python script setup the environment variables instead, I would recommend doing that.  `import os; env = os.environ; env['MYVAR'] = 'MYVALUE'; subprocess.check_call(['./run'], env=env)`